# How to download a .mov file using Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

When I use Internet Explorer to open a url like this: https://…/movie.mov, it automatically uses Windows Media player to open the link.

However, Chrome just tried to download the file. How could I make Internet Explorer just download the file instead of opening it?

Comment: I would say try using a software more dedicated to downloading, such as [**ReGet**](http://www.reget.com/en/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're suggesting you are typing in the address directly to the location bar, and not clicking on a web page link... then once the movie is playing in the windows media player, you should go to the File menu and select "Save As"... (follow normal save process).

If you're seeing a link to the movie you want from within a web page, you can simply "right-mouse" (or alternate-button) click over the link, and then select "Save Target As..." (follow normal save process).

If you mean you want to have other people use your web site, which has a .mov link and when they select it, the movie will download to their browser?.. then I am not sure of that situation.